# How to use escape quote in Bigquery query text?

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I defined and registered a UDF function in a query, but it looks like the big query doesn't like the escape quote `\"` in the function definition string, does anyone know how to use escape quote in bigquery?

This is my example:

```
SELECT
  Social_Connection,
  Device_Type
FROM
  js(
    -- input table
    (
    SELECT
      user_attribute.Name,
      user_attribute.Value
    FROM
      UDF_TESTING.testing_src ),
    -- input vars
    user_attribute.Name,
    user_attribute.Value,
    -- output schema
    "[{name: 'Social_Connection', type: 'string'},
   {name: 'Device_Type', type: 'string'}]",
    -- the function
    "function(row, emit) {
     var social_connection_index = 0;
     var device_type_index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < row.user_attribute.length; i++) {
    if (row.user_attribute[i].Name == \"Social_Connection\") {    // <------big query complains about the escape quote
      social_connection_index = i;
    }
    if (row.user_attribute[i].Name == \"Device_Type\") {   // <----- same as here
      device_type_index = i;
    }
  }
  emit( {Social_Connection: row.user_attribute[social_connection_index].Value,
         Device_Type: row.user_attribute[device_type_index].Value} )
}")
```

Comment: can you just use single quotes? row.user_attribute[i].Name == 'Social_Connection'

Comment: In this example I can, but I have some nested string using both single and double quote, I have to use escape characters..

Comment: in your example quotes are not part of string so you can safely use single quotes for them. \" and \' should work for when you use them within string. if this is not a case, would be great to see example. i just did quick dummy test and it works perfectly

Comment: But I want to know if I can use escape character in big query query text

Comment: as I said, it works for me  - if you can provide example that troubles you -i hope I will be able to show you

Comment: The \" is within a "" string (the code below `-- the function` is a string), in the example above, the big query JS compiler throw an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at line 6, columns 38-39`. If I change `\"` to `'`, the query will work, can you show me your working example using escape quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is dummy example, just to demonstrate how to use escape in both BQ SELECT itself as well as within JS function.
Hope this will help you!

```
SELECT Name, HasSingleQuote, HasDoubleQuote
FROM ( JS(
    -- input table
    (SELECT
      Name
    FROM
      (SELECT 'abc' AS Name),
      (SELECT 'a\'bc' AS Name),
      (SELECT 'a\"bc' AS Name),
      (SELECT 'a\"b\'c' AS Name)
      ),
    -- input vars
    Name,
    -- output schema
    "[{name: 'Name', type: 'STRING'},
   {name: 'HasSingleQuote', type: 'BOOLEAN'},
   {name: 'HasDoubleQuote', type: 'BOOLEAN'}]",
    -- the function
    "function(row, emit) {
      var hasSingleQuote = false;
      var hasDoubleQuote = false;
      if (row.Name.indexOf('\'') > -1) hasSingleQuote = true;
      if (row.Name.indexOf('\"') > -1) hasDoubleQuote = true;
      emit( {Name: row.Name,
         HasSingleQuote: hasSingleQuote,
         HasDoubleQuote: hasDoubleQuote
         } )
}"))
```

Output is:

```
Name    HasSingleQuote  HasDoubleQuote   
abc     false           false    
a'bc    true            false    
a"bc    false           true
a"b'c   true            true
```